# How to render two components so that both content shows on one page

Tags: reactjs

I have a login and signup form using modals. They both work just fine, but when rendering them in my home page only the login form will pop up for both but if I switch the order signup will show up for both. I'm not sure if I am missing something or need to wrap them up differently.

This is my signup but my login is pretty much the same just with different naming.

```
import React from "react";
import SignUp from "../SignUp";
import Login from "../Login";

const Home = () => (
    <div>
        <Login />
        <SignUp />
    </div>
);

export default Home;




import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class SignUp extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
        redirectTo: null
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
 };

 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
 };

 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // TODO - validate!
    axios
        .post('/auth/signup', {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response)

            if (!response.data.errmsg) {
                console.log('youre good')
                this.setState({
                    redirectTo: '/login'
                });
            } else {
                console.log('duplicate')
            }
        });
 };

 render() {
    if (this.state.redirectTo) {
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: this.state.redirectTo }} />
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data- 
            target="#exampleModal">Signup</a>

            <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" 
            role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria- 
            hidden="true">
              <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                <h5 className="modal-title" 
                id="exampleModalLabel">Sign Up</h5>
                <button type="button" className="close" data- 
                dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
               </div>

               <div className="container ">
                <div className="modal-body">
                 <div className="SignupForm">
                  <label 
                  htmlFor="username">Username</label><br />
                  <input type="text" name="username" 
                  value={this.state.username} onChange= 
                  {this.handleChange} /><br />
                  <label 
                   htmlFor="password">Password</label><br />
                   <input type="password" 
                   name="password" value={this.state.password} 
                   onChange= 
                   {this.handleChange}  /><br />
                   <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm 
                   Password</label> 
                   <br />
                   <input type="password" 
                    name="confirmPassword" value= 
                   {this.state.confirmPassword} onChange= 
                   {this.handleChange}/>
                   </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" 
                     data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} 
                    className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
};


export default SignUp;
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `Login` and `Signup` component as well?

Comment: added my sign up they both are pretty much are they same.

Comment: render() function is inside `class Signup`, right? Can you include that part as well?

Comment: I've already tried that. It throws me an error

Comment: No I mean can you show us the code for the whole Signup class, not just the render function?

Comment: Added the whole file

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: Missing the `login` component.

Comment: I have that. My forms work fine and it renders my button on the home page. I issue is that when I click on either button my login model pops up for both. if I switch the order to signup being first the form for sign shows for both.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of Bootstrap JS Modals will interfere with the proper functioning React's Virtual DOM.

Kindly use a react-compatible modal, such as: [Material-Ui Dialog](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Your component looks alright. Taking by your word, if they render perfectly on separate pages. Few points i'll want you to look for

1. If you are directly rendering them as two directly by attaching both components straightaway
   `render() {<div> <SignUp /> <Login /> </div> }`
2. If this causes you to open the same component twice, you might want to check the id's of these elements. It's quite probable that both of your components are defined by the same id and the one which renders first, gets called first.
3. Also, if you want to place some conditions on these components, you can assign them in states, and set them according to the conditions.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try and look over and see it that works.